# Php login password_verify

Tags: php, mysql

I am learning how to use prepared statements and I thought I would try out a login system (simple) using the `password_hash()` and `password_verify(`) functions. I have succesffuly inserted data in using prepared statemernts, now I wish to verify the password and do something with the user.

I seem to be getting back my fail message at this stage:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);

$username = $_POST['ulogin'];
$password = $_POST['upassword'];

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($username, $password);



$row = $stmt->fetch();
if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
    if (password_verify($password, $row['user_password'])) {
        echo 'success';
    }
} else {
 echo "Wrong data";
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

If I do a `var_dump($stmt->fetch());` and the login username is correct is comes back as `bool(true)`

Im not sure how to attempt to verify the password now.

Comment: cannot see your variable $row

Comment: @PhpDev oops sorry there you go

Comment: Does the $row['user_password']; give you the hash? if so, you should be getting a result. Add an else statement if password is not verified.

Comment: It just goes straight out the 'Wrong data'

Comment: Meaning the user does not exist. verify from your DB

Comment: but the user does exist, its happening at the password stage for sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135781/discussion-between-phpdude-and-phpdev).

Comment: Try if($stmt->num_rows >0).. the user might be duplicated in your Database, meaning more than one user of the same username exists

Comment: nope there is only 1 user in the table and database.

Comment: the felids are unique too for the username

Comment: you also need to store the results after you executed (when using `num_rows`) and make sure the password column's length is 60+. That is an often-made mistake

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<?php

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);

$username = $_POST['ulogin'];
$password = $_POST['upassword'];

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc(); //fetch DB results

if ($row && password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
    echo 'success'; // password_verify success!
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

You do not necessarily need to check for number of rows. Also have an else statement if the password is not verified for any reason

Comment: Sure, but [this comment I left them...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252986/php-login-password-verify#comment71664618_42252986) is another reason why it failed them, being the former.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of your problems:

```
$password = $_POST['upassword'];
...
$stmt->bind_result($username, $password);
...
if (password_verify($password, $row['user_password'])) {
```

You are overwriting your `$password` variable so it is no longer the posted value.

Using the POST value should solve the problem:

```
 if (password_verify($_POST['upassword'], $row['user_password'])) {
```

or

```
 if (password_verify($_POST['upassword'], $password)) {
```

as you have bound the password from the result to that variable.

Also, if your username in the database is unique, you can replace:

```
$row = $stmt->fetch();
if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
```

with:

```
if ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
```

Comment: issue is the password_verify line never gets executed. It halts at the num_rows check

Comment: @PhpDude I'm not that familiar with mysqli, but if your username is unique you can skip the `num_rows` check and just check if `$row` evaluates to `true`

Comment: What result now? if you use the if ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { }  it should evaluate to true if the user exists. Then proceed to verify the password.